# At what point did "gross" come to mean "disgusting"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, word-usage, history

The first time I heard "gross" being used to mean "disgusting" was probably around the late 1980s, and at the time I felt it was some sort of a corruption of "grotesque"...

I'm wondering if there is a longer history of this usage, or am I right in saying it stems from a more recent misuse?

Comment: Ngram easily finds [uses of "is gross" in this sense](https://books.google.com/books?id=P10AAAAAYAAJ&q=%22is+gross%22&dq=%22is+gross%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipqqmIrMfeAhXs1IMKHUrrBzYQ6AEIRjAF), going back to 1807, at least.

Comment: At least since Shakespeare wrote these lines in *Hamlet*: "[The world is] an unweeded garden / That grows to seed. Things rank and ***gross*** in nature / Possess it merely."

Comment: What is coarse is not fine, or refined.

Comment: Isn't italian "brutto" a very close parallel here, especially since it is used to mean "gross" in accounting too?

Answer (score 26):

"Gross" in its earliest definition dates back to at least the 1380s. The OED lists the following quote under "Of conspicuous magnitude; palpable, striking; plain, evident, obvious, easy to apprehend or understand. *Obsolete*.":

> Hoolynesse of lif techiþ rude men by groos ensaumple.
> <sub>[Wyclif's *English works*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme/AEH6713.0001.001/1:29?rgn=div1;view=fulltext), c1380</sub>

The word came from the French word *gros(se)* meaning "big, thick, coarse" and ultimately dates back to the lat Latin word *grossus* meaning "thick". Several of the other early quotes use it to mean "big". It's also the same word as "gross" meaning 144 and in "gross domestic product".

The [OED page for "gross"](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/gross_n3?tab=meaning_and_use#2533129) (meaning twelve dozen) is available for free with more information.

The earliest quote in the OED in the "disgusting" sense is from 1959:

> Terms expressing approval or disapproval are intelligible to the initiated only, for their real meaning is often dependent upon intonation. *Great, the greatest, gross*,..and *tremendous* are either complimentary or derogatory, depending upon how they are said.
> <sub>American Speech</sub>

It's likely that it's related to the older sense of the word meaning "[r]ude, uninstructed, ignorant" or "[e]xtremely coarse in behaviour or morals; brutally lacking in refinement or decency".

Comment: I'm not sure that 1959 quote really is using gross as "disgusting". The other words in that list (great, greatest, tremendous) have no inherent pejorative meaning whatsoever, they only take that meaning when said in a sarcastic manner. Any word with positive connotation can become negative when said sarcastically, so I don't see that as evidence that gross has an inherent derogatory meaning there.

Comment: @SolomonSlow The 1380 quote is for a different sense meaning "striking". You can see the full definition for the word from the OED above the quote.

Comment: Your first several paragraphs don't really have anything to do with the OP's question. I recommend removing them.

Answer (score 24):

As explained in the following extract, the meaning of disgusting was not a big semantic jump from the original meaning and usage of gross. This connotation appears to have become popular as a slang term among teenagers in the ‘60s/‘70s, but its earliest usage appears to date from 1958:

> - ***[Meaning "disgusting"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/gross) is first recorded 1958 in U.S. student slang***, from earlier use as an intensifier of unpleasant things ( gross stupidity , etc.) (Etymonline)

***[Gross:](http://mentalfloss.com/article/72497/how-did-gross-become-term-disgust)***

> The word gross has been in English for hundreds of years. We got it from French, where it means "big" or "fat." It took on a variety of senses in English related to size, including "coarse" (gross grains as opposed to fine), "strikingly obvious" (grosse as a mountaine), and "whole" (gross as opposed to net value). It also picked up negative senses like "vulgar," "crude" (Grose folke of rude affection Dronkerdes. Lubbers, knaues), or "ignorant" (a grosse unlettered people).
>
> ***From there it’s not a big jump to the current sense of disgusting. There’s always been something repulsive, or at least unsavory, in the word gross.***
>
> Gross did not undergo a big change in meaning, but it did undergo a big change in context. ***In the late 20th century, young people started to use it a lot—like, a lot a lot. So much so that old people noticed it, and didn’t like it.*** As one critic said in a 1971 issue of The Saturday Review, “Gross has always meant something coarse and vulgar. But as used by the teens, it runs the gamut of awfulness from homework to something the cat contributed to ecology.” ***Gross became slang.***

(mentalfloss.com)

Note also the usage of [gross-out](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/gross--out):

> (slang)
>   something that is disgustingly offensive.
>
> (First recorded in 1970–75; noun use of verb phrase gross out)

(Random House Unabridged Dictionary)

***Edit by WS2:***

Supplementary to this  answer, and also that of @Laurel, reproduced below is sense 15 of the adjective ***gross*** per the current online edition of the OED. Clearly the "student slang" to which Etymoline refers is closely related here.

The current online edition of the OED includes the following - to which the "student slang"

> ***15. Extremely coarse in behaviour or morals; brutally lacking in refinement or decency.***
>
> ```
> a. of persons.
> ```
>
> ?1533   G. Du Wes Introductorie for to lerne Frenche sig. Sii   Grose folke of rude affection Dronkerdes..Lubbers,
>   knaues.
>
> 1667   Milton Paradise Lost i. 491   Belial..then whom a Spirit more
>   lewd Fell not from Heaven, or more gross to love Vice for it self.
>
> 1693   Dryden tr. Juvenal Satires vi. 122   Agamemnon's Wife Was a
>   gross Butcher, with a bloody Knife.
>
> 1772   E. Burke Corr. (1844) I. 402   The Turks..grow more gross in
>   the very native soil of civility and refinement.
>
> 1881   Evans in Sp. Com. 1 Cor. Introd. 239   Society of high culture,
>   but in morals lax, even gross. absolute.
>
> ```
> b. of habits, language, pleasures, etc.
> ```
>
> 1598   Shakespeare Love's Labour's Lost i. i. 29   The grosser manner
>   of these worldes delyghts: He throwes vppon the grosse worlds baser
>   slaues.
>
> 1725   D. Defoe New Voy. round World i. 169   The Motive of their
>   Adoration being that of meer Terror, they have certainly gross Ideas.
>
> 1791   J. Boswell Life Johnson anno 1749 I. 103   [Paraphrasing
>   Johnson:] Some of them [sc. Juvenal's Satires]..were too gross for
>   imitation.
>
> 1877   ‘Rita’ Vivienne i. i. 15   Of life in its grosser, harsher
>   phases Albert knew scarce anything.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I associate the slang use in the 70's with Valley Girl language.

Comment: Valley Girl lingo also includes "grotty" (not sure of the spelling), as in "grotty to the max". That probably *is* a contraction of "grotesque".

Answer (score 1):

Gross appears to be word of Germanic origin. It appears not in classical Latin but in late Latin / early medieval Latin, when the Roman Empire relied heavily on foreign troops, many of them speaking early forms of German. Once it was absorbed in late Latin, it spread into Italian (grosso) and French (gros / grosse). In Dutch it became "groot".

In German, 'gross' simply means big but is used extensively in compound words from 1) Großvieh (big cattle), Grossmutter (grandmother) to Groß-Berlin (greater metropolitan area of Berlin). As it is and was used so often, it acquired all kinds of shadings from neutral (Grossmast, the tallest mast on a sailing ship) to positive (Großbild, a big-screen television) to negative (Großtuer, an arrogant, pompous person). The negative connotation encompasses things that are scarily, off-puttingly big. In German, however, to express disgust, "widerlich" or "ekelhaft" are usually employed, either alone or in combination with gross: "Das ist widerlich gross!"

1) [https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/gross?page=1](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/gross)

Comment: Ok but the question is about English usage, not German. So when did gross start to be used to mean “disgusting” in English?

Comment: Good point, to which I have no answer yet -- I might have to delete

Comment: When, I know not but medical students study "gross anatomy" which to the uninitiated is not significantly different from any other kind of "anatomy"… leaving "gross" looking for a meaning.

"gross" there really means "on the large scale" or "in general" or even just "broadly"… and not to Mr Average.

After getting used to dissecting bodies and slicing organs, the medics give it few further thoughts but until then, they physically shiver when they think thoughts such as "Uugh! Gross anatomy" and first in thought and then in speech they shorten that to "Uugh! Gross!"

Comment: Or on a different note, we used to joke that one should not use the number 288 in a poster presentation.

Comment: In German, *groß* has no negative connotation.

Answer (score 0):

I propose the word came from Francis Grose's 'Classical Dictionary of the Vulgar Tongue' first publish in 1785.  This dictionary defines slang words considered vulgar at the time.  It could be conceived that something unsavoury then became known by the author of defining such things.

"Grose, born in 1730, liked to eat rich foods and to drink port. He also liked to tell stories. A very fat man, he took pleasure in the pun linking his name to his size." (https://www.bl.uk/learning/langlit/dic/grose/vulgar1785.html)  Indicating that in 1785, the word 'gross' was more commonly used in relation to something/someone large or excessive.

Comment: Whilst your answer is an interesting historical footnote, Other answers seems to indicate its origin at least 400 years prior to this, not to mention its latin root going back another thousand and a half at least.

Answer (score -1):

In Chapter 1 of the Lord of the Rings ("A Long-Expected Party"), Bilbo offends some of the guests by noting there were 144 guests, which exactly matched the sum of his and Frodo's ages: "One Gross, if I may use the expression". Tolkien suggests that the insult may have been deliberate in the some cases, e.g. the Sackville-Bagginses. So I think it is safe to say that gross wasn't considered complimentary in 1954.

Comment: Hi Simon, welcome to our site. It's important to read the other answers before contributing your own. [This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/472180) comprehensively establishes that *gross* "wasn't considered complimentary" several hundred years before LOTR. I'm downvoting your answer simply because, as the downvote guidance says, "this answer isn't useful". You can always delete an answer if you wish to avoid downvotes. For further guidance, see [answer]. I encourage you to look for new questions to answer, and I also recommend taking the **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: It wasn't complementary because it was like ordering in bulk, like produce, instead of inviting individually for their personal merits.